# Converting Hierarchical Data to XML in Flex

Tags: xml, apache-flex

How to convert a flat/hierarchical data to XML format in Flex.
The following is my Hierarchical Data:(Table format)

```
Asia  India  Chennai  TN  Category1 Product1 100
Asia  India  Mumbai   MH  Category1 Product1 100
Asia  India  Calcutta CT  Category1 Product1 100
Asia  India  Calcutta CT  Category2 Product2 200
EMEA  UK     London   LN  Category3 Product1 123    
EMEA  UK     London   LN  Category3 Product2 455    
EMEA  UK     Reading  RN  Category1 Product1 500    
EMEA  UK     Reading  RN  Category1 Product2 430

        I need to format/convert this to XML format so that I can populate that resulting xml as dataprovider to a Tree control.
       Asia
         India
             Chennai
                TN
                  Category1
                     Product1
                          100
             Mumbai
                MH
                  Category1
                     Product1
                          100   
                                such a tree structure.
```

Comment: What delimiter symbols are used in the source file? Could you upload your source file to any server and give us a link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make a simple converter to get a real XML structure. The complexity of the solution depends on the source text you have.

Here is my implementation.

Suppose your hierarchical data is good structured and each element has a certain amount of whitespaces before. In my case I use 4 whitespaces as one level shift.

I load the data from a text file, which looks like this:

```
    Asia
        India
            Chennai
                TN
                    Category1
                        Product1
                            100
            Mumbai
                MH
                    Category2
                        Product2
                            200
                    Category3
                        Product3
                            300                  
                        Product4
                            400
```

Then I go through each string and analyse its level.
The resulting  tree looks like this:

[image]

// Application

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
           minWidth="955" minHeight="600" creationComplete="init(event)">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        private const SPACEDELIMITER:int = 4;
        private var loader:URLLoader;
        private var ar:Array = new Array();
        [Bindable]private var data:XML = <Root/>;
        private var inputStr:String;

        protected function init(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            loader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("com/treexml/tree.txt"));
            loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
        }

        private function completeHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            inputStr = URLLoader(event.target).data;
            parseString();
        }

        private function parseString():void
        {
            var levels:Array = new Array();
            ar = inputStr.split("\r\n");
            var reg:RegExp = /[a-z0-9]/gi;

            var globalShift:int = String(ar[0]).search(reg);

            for (var i:int = 0; i < ar.length; i++)
            {
                var item:String = ar[i];
                var shift:int = item.search(reg); //amount of witespaces before the text
                var level:int = (shift - globalShift)/SPACEDELIMITER; //level of the node
                var label:String = item.substring(shift, item.length);

                levels[level] = i; //id of the last element for the given level 

                var node:XML = new XML();
                node = <child id = {i} label = {label}/>;

                if (level == 0)
                    data.appendChild(node);
                else
                    data..child.(@id == levels[level - 1]).appendChild(node);
            }
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<mx:Tree width="250" 
         height="400" 
         dataProvider="{data.child}"
         labelField="@label"/>

</s:Application>
```

**//EDIT**

If your data is not aligned by means of whitespaces, try to use another edition of the parseString function.

Suppose your data looks like:

```
Asia India Chennai TN Category1 Product1 100
Asia India Mumbai MH Category1 Product1 100
Asia India Calcutta CT Category1 Product1 100
Asia India Calcutta CT Category2 Product2 200
EMEA UK London LN Category3 Product1 123
EMEA UK London LN Category3 Product2 455
EMEA UK Reading RN Category1 Product1 500
EMEA UK Reading RN Category1 Product2 430
```

The function is:

```
            private function parseString():void
{
    ar = inputStr.split("\r\n");
    var map:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
    var delimiter:String = "***";
    var id:int = 0;
    for (var i:int = 0; i < ar.length; i++)
    {
        if(ar[i].length){//if it's not an empty string
            var itemArray:Array = ar[i].replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ').split(" ");//collapse multiple spaces as one using RegEx
            var key:String = "";
            var prevkey:String = "";

            for (var j:int = 0; j< itemArray.length; j++)
            {
                prevkey = key;
                key += itemArray[j] + delimiter;

                if (map[key] == null)
                {
                    map[key] = id;

                    var node:XML = <child id = {id} label = {itemArray[j]}/>;

                    if (j == 0)
                        data.appendChild(node);
                    else
                        data..child.(@id == map[prevkey]).appendChild(node);

                    id++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the sincere try.But I would be getting dynamic data for which alignment of data with whitespaces for each data would be impossible for large data collection.I need a dynamic approach to this.

Comment: Could you explain which symbols will be used for describing the hierarchical structure? Which feature lets us tell children und parent apart? May be I can improve my approach. Do you have a real text, which could be parsed?

Comment: Do I understand right, that those strings such "EMEA UK London LN Category3 Product2 455" are the real data? Then it can be easier than my approach.

Comment: I have added another approach to my answer. May be it will help you.

Comment: Am working on buiding custom components for Xcelsius application(SAP product).The data I get would be from Excel,which I would be getting as "2D Array" which I have posted in my above question.I need to process the data so that it satisfies two criteria:
1.)The data needs to filtered to avoid duplicated rows.
2.)The filtered data needs to populated to a Tree component.,as in above question.

Comment: So I need to find a solution to identify the Parent folders and child folders,sub folders in it and finally leaf nodes according to the data I receive avoiding duplicacy in nodes.I have explored options regarding Data descriptors in Tree but there too the array that we provide is statically given.So that option is nullified I suppose.The next option is to convert the 2D Array to XML format which I tried using XMLDocument and Simplexmlencoder class.I need to add an attribute dynamically to that xml so that I can provide that attribute as "Labelfield" to the Tree component.This is the status.

Comment: @Peter Hall Can you let me know how to convert hierarchical data from excel as stated in above question to XML structure?., so that I can populate the tree accordingly.

Comment: Can you let me know how to convert hierarchical data from excel as stated in above question to XML structure?., so that I can populate the tree accordingly.

Comment: @Anton Your solution using descendants and two attributes is quite elegant (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a not so efficient approach using the recursive function form [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15877645/how-to-convert-xmllist-to-xml-in-flex/15885494#15885494):

```
var data:String = '';//this is just to keep the data in the editor, you would dinamically load this usually
data += 'Asia  India  Chennai  TN  Category1 Product1 100\n';
data += 'Asia  India  Mumbai   MH  Category1 Product1 100\n';
data += 'Asia  India  Calcutta CT  Category1 Product1 100\n';
data += 'Asia  India  Calcutta CT  Category2 Product2 200\n';
data += 'EMEA  UK     London   LN  Category3 Product1 123\n';    
data += 'EMEA  UK     London   LN  Category3 Product2 455\n';    
data += 'EMEA  UK     Reading  RN  Category1 Product1 500\n';    
data += 'EMEA  UK     Reading  RN  Category1 Product2 430\n';

trace(cleanNodes(parseTableString(data).*));

function parseTableString(str:String):XML{
    var lines:Array = str.split('\n');
    var xml:XML = <root />;
    for(var i:int = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
        //collapse multiple spaces to 1 using RegEx, then split
        var nodes:Array = lines[i].replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ').split(' ');
        for(var j:int = 0 ; j < nodes.length; j++){
            if(nodes[j].length){
                var node:String = '<item name="'+nodes[j]+'"/>';
                if(j > 0){//if the node has parents
                    var pre:String = '';//create enclosing tags
                    var post:String = '';
                    for(var k:int = 0 ; k < j; k++){//build up parent hierarchy
                        pre += '<item name="'+nodes[k]+'">';
                        post += '</item>';
                    }
                    node = pre+node+post;//concatenate as a full node
                    xml.appendChild(new XML(node));//add full node (will add duplicates)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return xml;
}

function cleanNodes(nodes:XMLList):XML{
    var parent:XML = nodes.parent();
    var result:XML = new XML("<"+parent.localName()+" />");//copy parent node name
    for each(var a:XML in parent.attributes()) result['@'+a.name()] = parent.attribute(a.name());//and attributes
    //merge duplicates at one level
    var found:Dictionary = new Dictionary(true);
    for each(var child:XML in nodes){
        var name:String = child.@name;
        if(!found[name]) {
            found[name] = child;
            result.appendChild(child);
        }else{//merge
            found[name].appendChild(child.*);
        }
    }
    //recurse
    for each(var kid:XML in result.*){//for each child node
        if(kid.*.length() > 0){//if it has children
            var clean:XML = cleanNodes(kid.*);//get a clean copy of each child node
            delete result.*[kid.childIndex()];//remove the original
            result.appendChild(clean);        //add the cleaned one (replace)
        }
    }
    return result;  
}
```

Which outputs:

```
<root>
  <item name="Asia">
    <item name="India">
      <item name="Chennai">
        <item name="TN">
          <item name="Category1">
            <item name="Product1">
              <item name="100"/>
            </item>
          </item>
        </item>
      </item>
      <item name="Mumbai">
        <item name="MH">
          <item name="Category1">
            <item name="Product1">
              <item name="100"/>
            </item>
          </item>
        </item>
      </item>
      <item name="Calcutta">
        <item name="CT">
          <item name="Category1">
            <item name="Product1">
              <item name="100"/>
            </item>
          </item>
          <item name="Category2">
            <item name="Product2">
              <item name="200"/>
            </item>
          </item>
        </item>
      </item>
    </item>
  </item>
  <item name="EMEA">
    <item name="UK">
      <item name="London">
        <item name="LN">
          <item name="Category3">
            <item name="Product1">
              <item name="123"/>
            </item>
            <item name="Product2">
              <item name="455"/>
            </item>
          </item>
        </item>
      </item>
      <item name="Reading">
        <item name="RN">
          <item name="Category1">
            <item name="Product1">
              <item name="500"/>
            </item>
            <item name="Product2">
              <item name="430"/>
            </item>
          </item>
        </item>
      </item>
    </item>
  </item>
</root>
```

Personally I think @Anton's answer it better since only adds nodes when it needs (as opposed to mine which creates duplicates, then removes them). I've added a RegEx to collapse multiple whitespaces into one into his answer as well.

Comment: Thanks infinitely.This works as expected but it treats Mexico City under Mexico as 'City' its child.,meaning it ignores it indicating duplicate.

Comment: Also there is one more concern, If there are two numerical data for a region,then it must come under one parent.Now it is considering one numerical data as parent to last data.Eg India->Chennai->Category 1->100->200 where I plan 100 to be my sales and 200 my Profit data under category1 of Chennai region,it must show 100,200 as child of Chennai rather than 200 as child of 100.

Comment: @Flexiflex re:Mexico: good demonstration why spaces are bad separators.that's why "Mexico City" also gets split into ["Mexico","City"], hence the extra node. `Mexico Mexico Mexico City  MC  Category2 Product1 200` becomes `<item name="Mexico">
    <item name="Mexico">
      <item name="Mexico">
        <item name="City">
          <item name="MC">
            <item name="Category2">
              <item name="Product1">
                <item name="200"/>
              </item>
            </item>
          </item>
        </item>
      </item>
    </item>
  </item>`...

Comment: `Mexico Mexico Mexico_City  MC  Category2 Product1 200` becomes `<item name="Mexico">
    <item name="Mexico">
      <item name="Mexico_City">
        <item name="MC">
          <item name="Category2">
            <item name="Product1">
              <item name="200"/>
            </item>
          </item>
        </item>
      </item>
    </item>
  </item>` which is closer to what you want, but although you see Mexico_City. You could have an extra check and if a label contains "_" in the label you could replace it with space **after** you parse lines, but it's still hacky. ...

Comment: ...do you have control over the data that comes from the server as tabular data ? if you can control the character you use as a separator this would be the cleaner solution. You can use something like **,** or `\t`(as in csv or tsv). The fact that the tabular data is nicely formated doesn't help that much in this case. Wouldn't Mexico be misaligned anyway ?

Comment: Regarding sales/profit , how does the original data looks like to reflect this ?

Comment: The sales profit data will be in additional columns (adjacent to 100 in my above table)that will contain only numerical datas like Sales(in Million) has `code` 100 200 where 100 represents data for a particular region ,200 for next data,so on and Profit as another column next to sales.

Comment: its not possible to control the data that comes from Excel.It can come dynamically too.

Answer (score 1):

If the only reason for converting to XML is for use as a Tree dataprovider, then you don't need to do that. A much more efficient way to approach is to use tree data descriptors. This lets you keep your data provider flat, and the descriptor lets you describe its structure so the tree knows what objects are children of each other. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7b69.html

Comment: I'm interesting in the final solution. Let us see it please.

Comment: @Peter Hall :I have checked the link before.They have hard coded the array detail statically.In my case I would get the array dynamically so in this case how to do?