# How to add subnodes to xml dynamically in Flex

Tags: xml, apache-flex, tree

I need to form a new xml so that I add the new nodes as sub childs to appropriate nodes as I parse the old xml thereby avoiding duplicates and adding the exact child to exact parent . I need to do this to populate the xml in a Tree as data provider in FLEX.

I have an xml like the following:

```
<root>
<item name="Asia">
  <item name="Asia"/>
  <item name="India"/>
  <item name="Mumbai"/>
  <item name="MH"/>
  <item name="Category 1"/>
  <item name="Product1"/>
  <item name="100"/>
  <item name="Category 2"/>
  <item name="Product1"/>
  <item name="200"/>
</item>
<item name="Asia">
  <item name="Asia"/>
  <item name="India"/>
  <item name="Calcutta"/>
  <item name="CT"/>
  <item name="Category 1"/>
  <item name="Product 1"/>
  <item name="100"/>
  <item name="Category 2"/>
  <item name="Product1"/>
  <item name="200"/>
  <item name="Category 3"/>
  <item name="Product2"/>
  <item name="200"/>
</item>
<item name="Mexico">
  <item name="Mexico"/>
  <item name="Mexico City"/>
  <item name="MC"/>
  <item name="Category 2"/>
  <item name="Product 1"/>
  <item name="200"/>
</item>
```

```
I need the output to be in XML so that 

  Asia 
  |  India 
  |     Mumbai
  |     |  MH
          |  Category 1
        |    |    Product 1
          |  |      100
          |  Category 2
          |     Product 1
        | |         200
        Calcutta
           CT
             Category 1
                 Product 1
                    100
             Category 2
                 Product 1
                    200
             Category 3
   |              Product 2
   |                 200
   Mexico
     Mexico City ......
```

Comment: to achieve it you need some meta information about the relationships among parents and children. Do you have it? How does one know whether "MH" is a child of "Mumbai" or "India"?

Comment: The above xml is a conversion of a hierarchical data(table data from excel)as in my previous question.,where each set of nodes indicate one row,where each subnode is a child of the upper node.So MH is the child of Mumbai and Mumbai is the child of India.
     I have converted that hierarchical 2D array data to XML form using SimpleXMLEncoder and jus added "name" attribute to all the nodes and  I need to further process this XML as in my above question to populate in tree.

Comment: @Flexiflex Did the solusions form your [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15834893/converting-hierarchical-data-to-xml-in-flex) not work ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `appendChild()` method of `XML` class

```
var xml:XML = 
        <body>
            <cat>Animals</cat>
        </body>;

xml.appendChild(<cat>Fish</cat>);




trace(xml.toXMLString()) will show the following output


<body>
    <cat>Animals</cat>
    <cat>Fish</cat>
</body>
```